# grunt dos NOT create css (sass to css) : Done, without errors

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

my os is Ubuntu 14.04

I'm Install Nodejs, Ruby, NPM and sass version : Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve)
I'm run "grunt sass" task in terminal! this task is running and show this message :

```
$ grunt sass
Running "sass:files" (sass) task

Done, without errors.
```

but dos not create a CSS file

config grunt file is here:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

    watch: {
        jsProject: {

            files: [
                '<%= jshint.project.src %>'
            ],
            tasks: ['jshint:project']
        },
        cssBootstrap: {
            files: [
                'sass/bootstrap/*.scss'
            ],
            tasks: [
                "sass:bootstrap"
            ]
        },
        sassProject: {
            files: [
                'sass/project/*.scss'
            ],
            tasks: [
                "sass"
            ]
        },
        cssProject: {
            files: [
                'css/project/*.css'
            ],
            tasks: [
                "csslint"
            ]
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        project: {
            src: ["js/project/*.js"],
            options: {
                jshintrc: "grunt/.jshintrc"
            }
        }
    },
    csslint: {
        options: {
            csslintrc: 'grunt/.csslintrc'
        },
        src: {
            bootstrap: "sass/_bootstrap.scss",
            project: "sass/project/include.scss",
            projectCss: "css/project/include.css"
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
        production: {
            options: {
                paths: ["sass"],
                cleancss: true,
                compress: true,
                ieCompat: true,
                strictImports : true,
                syncImport : true

            },
            files: {
                'css/style.min.css': '<%= csslint.src.project %>',
                'css/template.min.css': '<%= csslint.src.projectCss %>',
                'css/bootstrap.min.css': 'css/bootstrap.css'
            }
        }
    },




sass: {

            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                precision: 5
            },
            files: {
                'css/style.css': '<%= csslint.src.project %>'
            }

    },

    uglify: {
        project: {


          options: {
//                    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            files: {
                "js/script.min.js": ["<%= jshint.project.src %>"]
            }
        }
    }



});

grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
//  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-htmlhint");
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-concat");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');




grunt.registerTask("min", ["csslint", "cssmin","jshint", "uglify"]);
grunt.registerTask("default", ["watch"]);


};
```

package.json

```
   {
  "private": true,
  "name": "soroush-project",
  "title": "best practices for your project",
  "description": "masoud ui tasks",
  "author": "Masoud Soroush",
  "homepage": "http://soroush.co",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": ">=1.7"
    }

}
```

where is my problem ?

Comment: going to guess your path is incorrect. no input = no output. can you confirm that your input path `'<%= csslint.src.project %>'` is working? may want to change it to be explicit

Comment: i change to path  files: {
                    'css/style.css': 'css/project/include.css'
                } but not working and show this message >> File "sass/project/include.scss" changed.
Running "sass:files" (sass) task

Done, without errors.

Comment: sorry my i change path to  'css/style.css': 'sass/project/include.scss' but not outputting any css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you put the `files` setting inside the task and not inside a target. All Grunt tasks must have at least one target to run, in your case the target is named "files" (instead of you actually using a target and a nested `files` option). Try this:

```
sass: {
    allstyles: {  // <-- you needed another level
        options: {
            style: 'compressed',
            precision: 5
        },
        files: {
            'css/style.css': '<%= csslint.src.project %>'
        }
    }
},
```

And FYI, your "csslint" task also needs a target.

Answer (score -1):

If Grunt reports "Done, without errors" and you don't see expected results, try running the lib by itself.

In my case, I had a source-path typo in my Gruntfile.js sass task config...

Grunt didn't hear sass' underlying error when I ran the grunt sass task, and just reported "Done, without errors" when actually sass couldn't find the source file -- no css output file, but no GRUNT error either.

I ran sass by itself instead of the grunt sass task, and sure enough, sass complained: "errorno::NOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - src/sass/main.scss" -- I actually had my sources in src/scss, not src/sass.

Wasted 45 minutes trying to google what's wrong with sass.  :D

Comment: For the down-voters: Instead of just down voting this contribution, please supply why you are down voting.

Comment: Yeah, @kleinkie!  I agree, and like you I'd like to know why.